# Deriving the Cauchy-Riemann from the derivative of the complex conjugate.

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

I am trying to prove the Cauchy-Riemann conditions naturally arise from the condition that:

$$\frac{\partial f(z,z^{*})}{\partial z^{*}} = 0$$

But I'm having trouble starting from the definition of a derivative and get stuck:

$$\frac{\partial f(z,z^{*})}{\partial z^{*}} = \lim_{\Delta z\to 0}\frac{f(z,z^{*}_{0}+\Delta z)-f(z,z^{*}_{0})}{\Delta z}$$

Am I going about this the right way? Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

You've written the correct definition of the derivative.  But instead, note that

$$  \frac{\partial f}{\partial z^*}=\frac12\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right)\tag1 $$

Let $f=u+iv$ and set the right-hand of $(1)$ to $0$ .  Can you finish now?

Comment: Ok yeah I saw a post about that. That would give me f_x = -i*f_y (where the _ denotes a partial derivative). How would I get the other condition?

Comment: First let $f=u+iv$.  Then simplify.

Comment: Just got it! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  Pleased to hear this was useful.